# NetSuite Positive Pay Payment File Format - transHash not working

Tags: netsuite, freemarker

Anyone had any luck getting transaction info from a positive pay file template (Advanced Electronic Bill Payments module)?  Works fine in an EFT template, but not for the positive pay templates.  Even tried the exact documented option, with no luck.  And, I'm not having any luck Googling for it... :/

Example code returns data in EFT format, but not positive pay formats.

```
<#list payments as payment>
  <#list transHash[payment.internalid] as transaction>
    Reference Number : ${transaction.transactionnumber}
  </#list>
</#list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this has to be customized outside of the module.  According to NetSuite, this is an enhancement...  Even though it is documented as how you are supposed to do it... lol